# Trigger SP 2013 or 2010 Workflow from another workflow

Tags: 2013, workflow

I have created a REST API 2013 workflow that copies list information from a top level site to a sub site list.

I now have the requirement to start a workflow upon item creation in the sub site list.

As the list item has been created by 2013 workflow, the second workflow will not automatically start (item is created by SharePoint App).

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

If you built you 2013 Workflow with SharePoint Designer you should be able to start an SharePoint Desinger 2010 Workflow.

Under actions you should find "Start a List Workflow":
[image]

And if you clicked on that you can select the SharePoint 2010 Workflow:
[image]

Also a site workflow is possible.

As far as I know you can not start another SPD 2013 Workflow from an existing one.

Maybe a Workflow for a specific content type is also a possible solution...

Comment: I've started 2010 workflows from a 2013 as shown by Patrick in the past, definitely works.

Comment: Thanks for your response. As the 2nd list is in a sub site you cannot trigger it from the top level site list.

Comment: I think, I would create a new content type for that list and add a workflow to that.

Comment: Just thinking out loud here, haven't tried it but makes sense in my head. How about triggering a change in the subsite list item (Changing trigger column to yes), and in that list setting the workflow to run on item change (When trigger column = yes, run workflow, if no, go to end).

Answer (score 1):

As Patrick mentioned, you will not be able to start a SP2013 workflow through designer action. As an alternative, You can call a REST endpoint service to start your workflow in the same list or another list. Go through the following link for detailed description on how to create this.
[Call SP2013 workflow through REST API](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sridhara/2014/08/21/fix-sharepoint-2013-workflow-recursion-prevention-part-2/)

Answer (score 0):

As Karvannan said, you can call another SP2013 workflow via REST. However, if you are using SharePoint 2013 On-Prem, then be aware that you will require the May 2014 CU. I have tested this before with and without the patch in the past, and without it, the REST endpoints for this will not work.

If you find yourself in the situation of not being allowed to install this CU in your environment (as the client said no in my case), then consider creating an Event Receiver that is attached to the secondary list that will kick off the other workflow on item creation. The reasoning for the auto-start not working is by design to prevent the recursion issue, which is very valid. Fortunately, Microsoft did provide these REST endpoints as the lack thereof would cause common business functionality to be inhibited.

Answer (score -1):

iRunSharePoint – Start SharePoint 2013 Workflow, or https://spworkflowstart.codeplex.com/

Comment: Any explanation about the case? Why to use that tool?